# Starting web development with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For the last few years I have been using Firefox, Firebug, and the Web Devevloper Firefox toolbar for all my web dev needs, quite happily.  I am, however, very interested in experimenting with moving my web dev support over to Chrome, but I have no idea where or how to start.  How much functionality is build into Chrome and how do I access it?  What add-ins do I need and where do I learn about using them?

These are two of many questions I think face most web devs moving into a much less familiar environment.  I'm trying to ask a broader question here, along the lines of, what do I need to use and know for effective web deb and JavaScript debugging in Chrome and where is best to learn what I need to?

Comment: Most of what you need is included. Check out the [developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools).

Comment: You can also add Firebug to Chrome. http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome (as well as Safari) has really underestimated [`Developer Tools`](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) feature. Lots of developers are indifferent to it and use `Firebug` through habit. (to no purpose!)

But for me it is the main debug tool: it looks more pleasant than the latter and includes a way cooler features. (e.g. Timeline — separate time intervals for Loading, Scripting and Rendering).

**[Developer Tools Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)**.

Can't give up with Firebug? Have a look — [Firebug Lite](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench).

---

### More tools.

→ [Webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/);

→ [Speedtracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/index.html);

→ [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/).

→ From [google webmasters-faq](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#tools):

> There are several tools to help you test your website in Google Chrome:
>
> **Web Inspector**
> Right-click on any component on a web page to launch the web inspector. You'll be able to see the elements and resources associated with the component on which you clicked, including a hierarchy view of the DOM and a JavaScript console.
>
> **Task Manager**
> Select the **Page** menu icon, then **Developer > Task Manager** (or press **Shift+Esc**). The task manager shows all running Google Chrome processes, and the resources that they're using (memory, CPU, and network).
>
> **JavaScript Debugger**
> Select the **Page** menu icon, then **Developer > Debug JavaScript**. This launches a JavaScript debugger that can be used to attach to existing processes.

Comment: +1 for listing tutorial and nice comparison of other tools - thanks

Answer (score 1):

in chrome: right click and "Inspect Element"
the Light Version of Firebug is available too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) port from Firefox is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

While in Chrome, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> and start experimenting. It's all you'll need.